# why would my Mac "ring" when someone calls my Android cellphone?

Tags: macos, android, phone

When someone calls my Android cellphone (a 408 area code number that's served by Google Fi), my Mac laptop (running 10.14.6 (Mojave)) "rings".

Why?

I do *not* have any Nokia or other phone-related software installed on the Mac.

The phone does *not* have the Mac paired with Bluetooth.
Indeed, I can turn off Bluetooth on the phone, and the Mac will still ring.

My Google Fi phone number is *NOT* a google voice number, and has no association with google voice.

The "Apple Message" program ("app", sigh) on the Mac does not have a record of my phone number ... and if I disable it, the Mac still rings.  (I don't use the app, but it's there, so I thought I'd report on it :)

When the Mac "rings", there is *NO* other change on the desktop ... e.g., no window popping up with an "answer the phone" button or anything like that.

When the Mac "rings", *NO* new processes are created (according to "ps -ef" output), and none of the few that got CPU time before/during the ring look applicable to this feature/problem.

Although the phone and the Mac are on the same Wi-Fi, I can turn the phone's Wi-Fi off and the Mac will still ring.

I have no recollection of this happening prior to today (2020-10-31).

Comment: What applications do you have installed on the Android phone?  What Android/Google applications do you have installed on your laptop?  What browser are you using on the laptop?  Instead of submitting a comment, you should edit your question, to include this vital and necessary information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're logged into G-Mail. I have Fi and that's how it works. It's not the Mac, it's the site: Gmail.